# Twitter API limit on live streaming tweets through the "rtweet" R package

Tags: r, json, api, testing, twitter

I am currently live streaming tweets via the stream_tweets command based on a pre defined query, provided by the "rtweet" package. My only concern is whether I have some sort of limits from Twitter`s API?

Note that I am a beginner with regards to APIs, thus this question may be quite foolish.

Thank you

Comment: Please ask this at superuser.com, a sister Q&A site for power users

Comment: @psychonomics web services are off topic at [su]. Please check https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**  The stream_tweets section of the documentation references the link below, which states you have a rate limit of 10 requests per 60 seconds.

`https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/decahose-api/api-reference/decahose`

**Original**
The rtweet documentation says the rate limit for the standard search API
is 18,000 tweets per fifteen minutes.  This is on page 5 in the bearer_token function section.

`https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/rtweet.pdf`

Comment: I don`t think this applies as I am using the "stream_tweets" command not the "search_tweets"command.

Comment: To help other users answer this question, would you please provide a sample of your code.  Make sure to hide any private API keys